# ExifInterface not working on api 27

Tags: android

I'm having a problem shooting photos on Android 8.1 and get it to rotate correctly.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
           exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           logger.error("Error ExifInterface", e);
        }

        int rotation = 0;

        if (exif != null) {

            if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                rotation = 90; // When using the device in portrait, it passes here.
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                rotation = 270;
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                rotation = 180;
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                rotation = 90;
            }

        }

        bmp = ImageUtils.decodeFile(imageFile);

        if (rotation != 0) {
             Bitmap rotated = ImageUtils.rotate(bmp, rotation);
             bmp.recycle();
             bmp = rotated;
        }

        // here I use the image...

    }
}
```

It works on other devices I have (Android 7.0, 6.0 and 5.1). But didn't work on Android 8.1.

When shooting in portrait, ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION returns 6. It means to rotate 90 degrees. But the result image looks like this:

[image]

I took this photo in portrait. Before Android 8, it works correctly. But on Android 8.1 it looks like this.

Any idea why? Maybe on Android 8 I don't have to rotate it programmatically?

Comment: have you ever tried this with an emulator and a USB webcam? it's nothing new that certain camera devices require the image being rotated by `180°`, that's why having to rotate it by `90°` does not appear unlikely.

Comment: Have to rotate is not the problem. As I wrote, it works correctly on my other devices with Android 7.0. The image rotates 90 degrees and looks correct. On Android 8.1 it also rotates 90 degrees, but looks like the image above.

Comment: it is the question, if this is related to the hardware camera device's output or the vendor's software implementation ...with an emulator and a webcam, one can assume the orientation there (with API level 27 or 28) should be considered as "normal"; leaving the user a `Preference`, to rotate by `90°`, `180°` and `270°` might be a possible workaround... the SDK sources package for API level 27 would be available, in order to verify.

Comment: It looks weird to me. As a user, does matter if I took the photo in landscape or portrait, the result of it should always show in the correct rotation. iOS does that. Doesn't matter in which position you took a photo, the callback always return in correct rotation.

Comment: well, with `iOS` you have a single one hardware vendor ...

Comment: I will add a edit photo screen for the user to rotate it manually

Comment: if this is issue should originate from specific camera hardware (or >= API 27), each single image would have to be manually rotated; that's what preferences are made for (compared to a repetitive task of doing that manually).